# Evaluate the following infinite sum with parameter

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation, improper-integrals, parametric

So the sum actually originates from the following integral:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor}{x^{a + 1}}dx$$
where $a$ is a real parameter. I've managed to transform the integral into the following sum (except for the case $a = 0$, which is observed separately), which actually became a lot more interesting for me:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{a}(\frac{(n+1)^a - n^a}{n^a(n+1)^a})$$

But I'm clueless as to how to approach that sum? Any ideas? I'm really keen on figuring this out! Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $$\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x^{a+1}}\underset{x\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\frac{1}{x^a}$$ 
thus the integral converges iff $a>1$. What you did is 
$$ \int_1^{+\infty}{\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x^{a+1}}dx}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\int_n^{n+1}{\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x^{a+1}}dx}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{n\int_n^{n+1}{\frac{dx}{x^{a+1}}}}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n}{a}\left(\frac{1}{n^a}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^a}\right) $$
Let $N\in\mathbb{N}^*$, we have that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^N{n\left(\frac{1}{n^a}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^a}\right)}=\sum_{n=1}^N{\left(\frac{1}{n^{a-1}}-\frac{n}{(n+1)^a}\right)}=\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac{1}{n^{a-1}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{a-1}}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^N{\frac{1}{(n+1)^a}}=1-\frac{1}{(N+1)^{a-1}}+\sum_{n=1}^N{\frac{1}{(n+1)^a}}\underset{N\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\zeta(a)$$
This only works if $a>1$, otherwise the integral diverges as it was expected. You finally have
$$ \int_1^{+\infty}{\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x^{a+1}}dx}=\frac{\zeta(a)}{a} $$

Comment: Thank you a lot! Really exciting work, I managed to wrap my head around all of it!

Answer (score 3):

$HINT$

$n\frac{(n+1)^a-n^a}{n^a(n+1)^a}=\frac{n}{n^a}-\frac{n+1-1}{(n+1)^a}=\frac{1}{n^{a-1}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{a-1}}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^a}$

Now take cases for $a$

For $a=1$ the series diverge.

Comment: right idea to split , but third part is mistaken

Comment: @GCab I edited my answer..thank you for the correction..But  i do not see if this sum  can be calculated explicitly

Comment: first two telescopes, third involves the zeta function

Comment: @GCab i know..what  with explicitly  i meant to find some numerical value..but we have to use the zeta function indeed.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Yes, it turned out indeed, that the zeta function is required.